# How to change the linkcolor of a hyperlink using hyperref?

Tags: hyperref, color

So basically I would like the hyperlink in my pdf file to be blue, for no particular reason other than my my personal preference. It seems unable to do that. Maybe I midsunderstood what linkcolor is meant for?

Below is a MWE of my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
...


Go to \href{https://www.dingtalk.com/en} and download Dingtalk suitable for your laptop. We will primarily use Dingtalk to communicate with you.
...

\end{document}
```

It seems to be red regardless of what color I specify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

linkcolor is for internal links.  Here's your example with the url in green and an internal link in blue

```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, urlcolor = green]{hyperref}
   \begin{document}
   \section{Intro}
   \label{section:intro}
   Go to \href{https://www.dingtalk.com/en}{Dingtalk} and download
Dingtalk suitable for your laptop. We will primarily use Dingtalk to
communicate with you (see Section~\ref{section:intro}).

   \end{document}
```

[image: image of output generated by the code above]